# The click-to-favorite button has unexpected behavior when using multiple tabs or the back button

Tags: bug, bookmarks

Try the following steps:

1. Open this question in two different tabs.
2. Favorite it in the first tab.
3. Look at the icon in the second tab. It appears not to be favorited.
4. Click the favorite icon in the second tab, causing the question to appear to be favorited.

The question now appears to be favorited in both tabs, but in fact is not. Your second click on the button unfavorited it.

Alternatively, another way to fall into the same trap:

1. Favorite this question.
2. Follow any link on the page.
3. Click the 'back' button in your browser.
4. Look at the favorite icon. The question appears not to be favorited.
5. Click the favorite icon again.

The question now appears to be favorited once more. However, it isn't. Again, your second click unfavorited it.

When hastily researching some issue, I frequently follow links and then click 'back', or follow loads of links and end up with multiple instances of the same question open in different tabs. As such, I've fallen into both of these traps a few times in reality.

The better behavior would be if clicking an unhighlighted favorites icon always caused the question to become favorited, regardless of whether it currently is or not, and clicking a highlighted one always caused it to become unfavorited. The icon's state becoming out of date doesn't bother me, but the fact that I can accidentally end up unfavoriting something I want favorited bothers me a little.

Any chance of a fix?

Comment: As far as the back button, there's absolutely nothing we can do about that. Using the back button attempts to restore the page the way you last saw it, but most often ends up the way you *originally* saw it when you first opened the page, because elements altered by JavaScript are not saved. The *only* solution to the back button problem is "don't do that."

Comment: The real question here is **Why do you have a question opened in two tabs?**

Comment: @animuson You may not be able to fix the way the favorite button appears when the page loads, but you *can* fix what happens when I click it. Just having clicking the button either trigger a "Favorite this question" API call or an "Unfavorite this question" API call depending upon its state (rather than a "Toggle whether this question is favorited" API call like it does currently) would remove both the traps described here, making the misreporting of whether the question is favorited innocuous.

Comment: @ColeJohnson All kinds of reasons. Maybe I thought I'd already closed the first tab, but really I hadn't. Maybe I follow a link to the question from Google, and then follow a "This answer might help you" link from another related question, not knowing I'm going somewhere I've already visited. Maybe I do a couple of Google searches and open the top 10 results from each of them in tabs, and there's some overlap that I don't notice at first. I'm a messy browser; I do stuff like this all the time. I'm not sure whether that's typical or not, so naturally YMMV.

Comment: @MarkAmery You forget that this issue would happen with *anything* that uses JavaScript to update things. If you close a question, visit a link, then hit back, the question will appear open. Should submitting another close vote still go through? No. The same issue would affect upvotes, downvotes, the accept mark. It's a toggle because that's easier to deal with server-side. Why can't you just *remember* that you've already favorited it?

Comment: No, if you want the page you used the back button to get to to better reflect its current status, hit refresh. Period. I see this kind of issue all the time and I know precisely that the contents are stale because I used the back button. F5 is not very difficult.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't mind either way whether it does or not, as I already made explicitly clear in response to animuson's first comment. The issue is that the behaviour upon clicking the button is unexpected, not that the current status is misreported.

Comment: If you see that an icon is not lit up and you recognize that it should be - because you just favorited it a few seconds ago, in a different window, what have you - then refresh the page.

Comment: @animuson Now that I know the trap exists, I can and do just remember whether I favorited the question, or refresh if I'm not sure, but it caught me out many times before I realised the issue was there. If I come along to an old tab half an hour later and see a question unfavorited, my instinct as a user is to think "hmm, maybe I'm wrong and I didn't favorite it after all" and click the button just to be sure. The misreporting doesn't matter, but clicking the button shouldn't ever do the opposite of what it claims it will.

Comment: You could also refresh the page to check. Or go look at your favorites tab (and refresh that if it is already open).

Comment: This is indeed strange behaviour. I almost support it being a bug rather than a feature request. **Irrespective of the true favourite state** a filled star is an unfavourite button and an unfilled star is a favourite button. The fact that only one is ever visible and they sit in the same place is a visual nicety;  both buttons should fulfil their promised function

Comment: I'm sure I posted this years ago, can't find it now - must have been deleted. Anyway, I totally agree.

Comment: As noted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174634/bug-in-toggling-of-favorites), this behavior does not occur with the upvote/downvote toggle, only the favorites star button. If clicking an unfilled upvote arrow in two tabs leaves you with an upvoted question, clicking an unfilled favorite star in two tabs should leave you with a favorited question.